# Angular 7 with Express server Routing Issue

Tags: angular, express

I was able to setup express server for my angular app but ran into a small issue. When I start the server the first page loads fine but when I try to navigate to a different url, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (/Users/sumanthjois/Downloads/frontend/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:61:11)
    at Function.render (/Users/sumanthjois/Downloads/frontend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/sumanthjois/Downloads/frontend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at /Users/sumanthjois/Downloads/frontend/server.js:56:7
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/sumanthjois/Downloads/frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/sumanthjois/Downloads/frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /Users/sumanthjois/Downloads/frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/sumanthjois/Downloads/frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/sumanthjois/Downloads/frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/sumanthjois/Downloads/frontend/server.js:39:3
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/sumanthjois/Downloads/frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/sumanthjois/Downloads/frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/sumanthjois/Downloads/frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/sumanthjois/Downloads/frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/sumanthjois/Downloads/frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/sumanthjois/Downloads/frontend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
```

Following is my **server.js** file:

```
require('dotenv').config();
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var passport = require('passport');
require('./app_server/models/db');
require('./app_server/config/passport');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;


var indexRouter = require('./app_server/routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./app_server/routes/users');

var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'frontend')));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);


app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/frontend/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Running the server on port ' + port);
});
```

I am setting the static files and even sending the file as a response. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Whether the next navigation url hits the wildcard route in your express app

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I am new to this stuff. sorry

Comment: Okay, the thing is in case of angular app being served, the "domain/" route and all other routes except for the api end points, the index.html of the angular app should be served. This is done so that all routes other than the api points should be handled by the router in angular. For all other routes, you have written a middleware where you serve the index.html, the get('*') route. Kindly confirm by adding a console.log statement in that route and see whether the urls except for api endpoints and '/', reach that middleware.